# Resolve IP next hop with socket programming on Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, mac-address, arp

Working with Linux.
Given a specific destination IP address, I need to populate the ARP cache with its next hop MAC address and interface.
Other mechanism in my software project will take this MAC address and push it to an FPGA.

If I open a TCP connection to the address it will be resolved and TCP handshake packets are sent. If I open a UDP socket and 'connect' it to the address it will not be resolved. If I send a single packet over the connected UDP socket it is resolved.

[arp(7) documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/arp.7.html) explains this: "... Requests are sent only when there is data queued for sending".

I can't call the 'arp' utility directly.

My question: is there a way to convince the system to populate an address by sending ARP in the background without the need for actually sending a packet?
I hope for some ioctl or setsockopt.

I prefer a generic solution that will also work for IPv6 neighbor resolution.

Thanks,
Gur

Comment: Why can't you call the [arp(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/arp.8.html) utility directly?

Comment: One reason is that for some reason my embedded system doesn't have arp. This could probably be fixed. Another reason is that I only know the target IP. I don't know the next hop IP and don't know the interface through which I need to egress. This need to be figured from the routing tables and I rather not go there.